# Grouping parent-child objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am grouping objects in a table.
For now I have a short working example on
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mAG0qBg56LcDp42vyVNF?p=preview)

Now I want to group multiple child objects to one parent object.
The structure I want to achieve is

```
companyName(1), workers(3)
    worker name(1), some job
    worker name(2), some job
    worker name(3), some job

companyName(2), workers(4)
    worker name(1), some job
    worker name(2), some job
    worker name(3), some job
    worker name(4), some job
```

What is the best way to achieve this in angular?
Is there an article about this?
I tried looking myself but I couldn't find what I need.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Quite easy with nested ngRepeat, but your data structure is not ready for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange your data in the following structure.

```
$scope.companies = [
        { id: 0, name: "Meiks",  workers:[
            { id:1, firstName:"Joel", lastName:"Cash" },
            { id:2, firstName:"Christian", lastName:"Hamilton" },
            { id:3, firstName:"Cornelius", lastName:"Baldwin" }
        ]}  
        // ......
```

Use `ng-repeat` to render them.

```
    <div ng-repeat-start="company in companies" class="header">{{company.name}}</div>

       <div ng-repeat="worker in team.workers">{{worker.firstName}} {worker.lastName}}</div>

    <div ng-repeat-end><br /></div>
```